# Retrieving contacts via old account to new one

Tags: icloud

What if you bought a new iPhone so when you transferred your contacts your previous contacts via the old iCloud account, then you sign out of the old iCloud account into a new one. The contacts then disappeared, so how do you now retrieve the contacts?

Comment: Why a new iCloud account? Why not just keep the old one? Accounts are transferable to new devices. Can even be used on several personal devices.

Comment: I changed the old iCloud account because our family shares the same iCloud account and the things being downloaded by my relatives keep on syncing in the iPhone, so yeah I changed the iCloud account to avoid the syncing of things I don't want in the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You may retrieve them by doing the following.

1. Open any web browser, and go to icloud.com on your computer.
2. Log in with your iCloud account (Your Apple ID and password).
3. Click on Contacts. Click the gear shaped Settings button on the bottom left, and click Select All.
4. Click the gear button again, and click Export vCard… to download contacts from iCloud.

Then, you reupload by signing in with the other Apple ID following these steps.

1. In iCloud Contacts, click the Action pop-up menu  in the sidebar, then choose Import vCard.
2. Select a vCard to import.